# Finding vertices of a simple graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Not sure how to go about solving this. If anyone has a hint on how to start this, that would be great!

If G is a simple graph with no self-loops with 17 edges and complement of G has 19 edges, how many vertices does G have? Explain how you got your answer.

Comment: Wait... so how many edges does $G$ have?  17? or 19?  You said two different things in the same line.  Is it that $G$ has $17$ edges and something else has $19$ edges?  What is that something else?  The line graph of $G$?  The graph complement of $G$?

Comment: The complement of G has 19 edges

Comment: You should correct your post then with that information.  Now that that ambiguity is out of the way, what do you know about what a graph complement is?  If we were to consider the union of the edge set of $G$ with the edge set of the complement of $G$, what type of graph does that make?  How many edges does *it* have?  If it has $n$ vertices, how many edges does it have in terms of $n$?

Comment: The graph complement is the edges that are not in G so if G has 17 edges this would mean that there are 19 ways that G is not connected?

Comment: That is not what I was trying to get at.  $G$ has some edges and $G'$ (*what I'll use to denote the complement of $G$*) has all of the edges that $G$ doesn't have and none of the edges that $G$ does have.  If we were to combine $G$ and $G'$ by taking the graph union, then we have *all* possible edges for our vertices, what is called a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph).

Comment: Stop a moment and make sure you understand why.  For a visual demonstration, imagine if you will that you start with a complete graph and you colored some of the edges blue and the rest of the edges red and all of the vertices black.  The graph with the vertices and the edges that are blue would be $G$ and the graph with the vertices and the edges that are red would be $G'$.  Now... what do you know about complete graphs and how many edges they have.  In our specific problem, how many edges came from $G$?  How many edges came from $G'$?  How many edges then are in $G\cup G'$?

Comment: For a complete graph, the number of edges can be found by using the formula n(n-2) where n is the number of vertices given.
If there are 17 edges in G and 19 in the complement, if combined, there would be a total of 36 edges in the complete graph of G. Now that we know the total number of edges, using the formula would give us the number of vertices
Is this the right approach?

Comment: Close but not quite.  The number of edges in a complete graph on $n$ vertices is not $n(n-2)$.  The phrase "$n$ choose $2$" *should* ring a bell.  The approach is correct, there are indeed $36$ edges in this complete graph, and knowing the correct formula for the number of edges we should be able to find $n$ by setting the formula equal to $36$, but you need to first get the correct formula for the number of edges in a complete graph.

Answer (score 4):

We know that, when we join $G$ and its complement together, we have a complete graph with $17 + 19 = 36$ edges. Since in a complete graph all vertices are connected and therefore $|E| = |V|(|V|-1)/2$, we know that $|V| = 9$.

Now, we'll construct one such graph. Consider a graph with $9$ vertices arranged in a circle, with every vertex connected to every vertex that's either 1 or 2 away in the circle. This graph has $18$ edges. Remove an arbitrary one, and there's your $17$.

Comment: Thanks. Edited.

Comment: 36 vertices????